# How to install TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm new to TFS on Visual Studio 2012 and I found the TFS 2013 Express edition to install. The thing is my friend and I are working on a project and we wanted to sync our version to either of us computer. Currently, we don't have a server to say but is it possible to use one of our computers as a server and install TFS on it and sync our projects? Does it require Internet connectivity whenever we want to sync? Can we use local area connection to do the sync? Do we need TFS to be installed on both of our computers?

A link to installation guideline would also be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It might be worth investigating Visual Studio Online for your project -- you get all the features of TFS, without the need for installing stuff on-prem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **the guide** you need to plan your Team Foundation Server installation:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035

Comment: Having said that, to install TFS express I just ran the installer and it did everything for me. When running outside of a domain you may need to provide name and password from time to time, but otherwise it was very easy to set up.

Comment: Much has improved since TFS 2005/2008

Answer (score 2):

TFS works perfectly well over a LAN.  At the end of the day it's just a HTTP server, so as long as either you and your friend are on the same network, or if not, the necessary ports are open on the router, he can connect fine via the internet.  Doesn't matter which one of you hosts it.

You do not need TFS on both computers, Visual Studio will happily connect to it once you provide the details (Access from the Team Menu, and Team Explorer).